# How to fix a JSON Text in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to make a command using JSON for a map, obviously i'm testing commands in case they try and break on me. I tried making a multi-colored tellraw command and it either does one part, or the other here's the command

> /tellraw @a {"text":"(YOU!)","color":"blue","Bold":"true","text":"Rawr.","color":"red","bold":"true"}

I've tried making it to were its like

> /tellraw @a {"text":"(YOU!)","color":"blue","Bold":"true"},{"text":"Rawr.","color":"red","bold":"true"}

but it still doesn't work, anyone can pick up and show my mistakes i've made?

Comment: What version of Minecraft are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is incorrect because to chain multiple `json` string definitions together, you need to arrange them in an array.

Arrays are defined using the square `[]` brackets.
A compound bracket; curly `{}` brackets can only be used for nesting other constants.

In theory, you need to do this:

```
/tellraw @a [{"text":"(YOU!)","color":"blue","Bold":"true"},{"text":"Rawr.","color":"red","bold":"true"}]  
            ^                                                                                           ^
```

Might I also add, multiple strings in an array are explictly added, so (without color), your text will look like this:

> (YOU!)Rawr.

You may want to add a space into one of the strings to denote seperation.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`tellraw @p {text:"YOU!",color:blue,bold:true,extra:[{text:"Rawr.",color:red,bold:true}]}`

P.S: If you want to make another line on the `text:"Rawr."` part, just change the `text:"Rawr."` part into `text:"\nRawr."`.